# Can I use symbolic tensors for simple linear algebra and calculus?

Tags: tensors

As an example, I'd like to calculate this symbolic derivative:

> $\frac{\partial}{\partial b}(x-A.b)^{\mathsf{T}}.(x-A.b)$

where $x$ and $b$ are vectors and $A$ is a matrix.

What I tried is this:

```
Clear[x, a, b, n, m]    
$Assumptions = {x ∈ Vectors[n, Reals], a ∈ Matrices[{n, m}], b ∈ Vectors[m, Reals]}

expr = TensorReduce[(x - a.b).(x - a.b)]
```

The value returned by `TensorReduce` looks ok, in the sense that `TensorRank` and `TensorDimensions` return `0` and `{}` as expected for a scalar, and when I use replacement rules to replace `x`, `a`, `b` with proper-sized arrays, I get the expected result.

However, when I write:

```
D[expr, b]
```

I get the expression: `-2 x.a.1 + a.1.a.b + a.b.a.1`. Looking at this expression, I can sort of guess what the derivative should look like, but I can't use it in code like that. For example, I can't use `TensorDimensions` to get the derivative's dimension, and I can't use replacement rules to insert arrays in place of the symbolic tensors.

**ADD**:

I've also tried using `TensorProduct`/`TensorContract` instead of `Dot`:

```
xmab = TensorReduce[x - TensorContract[TensorProduct[a, b], {{2, 3}}]];    
expr = TensorReduce[
   TensorContract[TensorProduct[xmab, xmab], {{1, 2}}]];
```

This gives a sensible looking `expr`, but I think `D` doesn't work with `TensorProduct`/`TensorContract`:

```
D[expr, {b, 1}]
```

> -2 (TensorContract^(1,{{0,0},{0,0}}))[a[TensorProduct]b[TensorProduct]x,{{1,4},{2,3}}] (TensorProduct^(0,1,0))[a,b,x]+(TensorContract^(1,{{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}}))[a[TensorProduct]a[TensorProduct]b[TensorProduct]b,{{1,3},{2,6},{4,5}}] ((TensorProduct^(0,0,0,1))[a,a,b,b]+(TensorProduct^(0,0,1,0))[a,a,b,b])

Comment: I think calculus functions (`D`) don't work with tensors.  `D` seems to work with `Dot`, but it does give a weird looking result that I don't understand: `1 . x` (anyone copying this, note the space around the `.`).  This type of expression will never evaluate `1 . 2` or `1 . {1,2}`.  I would have expected `Dot` to act as `Times` with scalars ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: I've noticed that `Dt[f.g, x]` is `f.Dt[g, x] + Dt[f, x].g`: MMA seems to apply the product rule to `Dot`, so I'd say the `1` in `1 . x` should be the Jacobian `D[x,x]`, i.e. `IdentityMatrix`. (Did that make sense?). So I could probably safely replace `Dot[x_,1] -> x`. But I can't get the transpositions right, because `D` doesn't seem to work with `Transpose`, `Transpose` doesn't distribute over sums and so on.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?