# Symbolic matrix calculus: What's new in Version 9

Tags: matrix, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have seen some of the related posts, which ask about doing matrix calculation on tensors unknown dimensions. One of the posts mentioned that version 9 has some capability, but it was concerned about simple matrix algebra, but not calculus.

I would specifically like to know if with the addition of Tensor package in version 9, if the following is possible:

$a, \lambda \in R^n$, and  $C\in R^{n\times n}$
Here $n$ is unknown/symbolic variable.

I am trying to find derivative of expressions which involve matrix-vector products such as (to give a simple example)
$f(a,\lambda)=\dfrac{\lambda^T Ca}{\sqrt{a^T C a}}$

I would like to know if using Mathematica we can find expressions of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ etc.

Thanks.

Comment: version 9? That's almost 2 years old now... did you mean 10?

Comment: I mention version 9 since it seems to me thats when the Tensor package was added. I don't know if 10 adds anything more to this functionality.

Comment: AFAIK these things are not possible, not out of the box. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/can-i-use-symbolic-tensors-for-simple-linear-algebra-and-calculus

Comment: Thats disappointing, if true.

Comment: A similar question was asked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/can-mathematica-do-symbolic-linear-algebra regarding purely symbolic computations of vector derivatives of matrix/vector expressions of unspecified rank. AFAIK it's not straightforward to do, unfortunately.

Comment: Any idea if NCAlgebra package from UCSD can really do this stuff ? Hard to believe this doesn't exist yet in any computer software.